# Providing an estimate for $|x|/(1+\sqrt{|x|})^{2}$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto |x|/(1+\sqrt{|x|})^{2}$. Can we find constants $c,a \in \mathbb{R}$, $c>0,0<a<1$ such that $f(x)\geq c |x|^{a}$ (at least in some neighborhood of 0)? I can prove this estimate for $a=1$ but I feel one can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **no**.

When $x\to 0^+$, you have
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2} = x\left(1-2\sqrt{x} + o(x)\right)
= x+o(x)
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{}1.
$$
From this, there is no hope to show $\lvert f(x)\rvert \geq C \lvert x\rvert^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $C>0$ on a neighborhood of $0$, as this would imply, for $x>0$,
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha}\cdot \frac{x^\alpha}{x} \geq \frac{C}{x^{1-\alpha}} \xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{}\infty
$$

Comment: Nice answer! Shame for it though, really wanted it to work.

Comment: Sorry about that :)

Comment: @followerofdanu By the way, if that answered you question, consider accepting it ($\checkmark$ on the left).

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did but only upvoted it.